# Nested jQuery Selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there anyway to have nested jQuery selectors.

**For example:**

if the page also has an `ID = "LeadEditForm_Title"` someplace on it then do the following...

```
jQuery("[id='A0.R0.Main Phone Number']").live('mousedown',function(e) {
    var container = $(this).width();
    var width_offset = -50;
    var top_offset = 25;
    var width = (container + width_offset).toString();
    jQuery(".mywidget").appendTo(document.body).css('width', width + 'px');
    jQuery(".mywidget").appendTo(document.body).css('position', 'absolute');
    jQuery(".mywidget").appendTo(document.body).css('top', ($(this).offset().top+top_offset).toString() + 'px');
    jQuery(".mywidget").appendTo(document.body).css('left', Math.round($(this).offset().left) + 'px');
});
```

**QUESTION:**

How do I do an if `jQuery(".LeadEditForm_Title")` then do the above??? basically a nested jQuery call... I've seen examples where they have :

```
 jQuery(function(){ // my code goes here });
```

But I want it to depend on the ID "`.LeadEditForm_Title`".

Comment: As far as i can tell, that function seems fine.

Comment: Does your ID really have spaces in it?  HTML spec says that IDs cannot have spaces.  Normally you select IDs with `#`.  I.e. `$("#myID")`.

Comment: Why `mousedown` and not `click`? also ids aren't supposed to have spaces like that, I doubt it'll validate. You could use `data` instead...

Comment: What I'm looking to do is... if(jQuery("someselectorid") then do some thing else...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To nest selectors, you use `find`:

```
jQuery('#mySelectorId').find('.mySelectorClass')
```

This is the same as doing this as well:

```
jQuery('#mySelectorId .mySelectorClass')
```

Being sure to put a space between.  Without the space you are selecting an element with that ID **and** that class.

I would also note that your code is probably not doing what you think it is:

```
jQuery("[id='A0.R0.Main Phone Number']").live('mousedown',function(e) {
    var container = $(this).width();
    var width_offset = -50;
    var top_offset = 25;
    var width = (container + width_offset).toString();
    jQuery(".mywidget").appendTo(document.body).css('width', width + 'px');
    jQuery(".mywidget").appendTo(document.body).css('position', 'absolute');
    jQuery(".mywidget").appendTo(document.body).css('top', ($(this).offset().top+top_offset).toString() + 'px');
    jQuery(".mywidget").appendTo(document.body).css('left', Math.round($(this).offset().left) + 'px');
});
```

The last 4 `jQuery(".mywidget")` calls are adding the widget to the body each time.  You really only want to add it once and change the css for each style:

```
jQuery("[id='A0.R0.Main Phone Number']").live('mousedown',function(e) {
    var container = $(this).width();
    var width_offset = -50;
    var top_offset = 25;
    var width = (container + width_offset).toString();
    jQuery(".mywidget").appendTo(document.body).css('width', width + 'px').css('position', 'absolute').css('top', ($(this).offset().top+top_offset).toString() + 'px').css('left', Math.round($(this).offset().left) + 'px');
});
```

Which can also be reduced to one css call:

```
jQuery("[id='A0.R0.Main Phone Number']").live('mousedown',function(e) {
    var container = $(this).width();
    var width_offset = -50;
    var top_offset = 25;
    var width = (container + width_offset).toString();
    jQuery(".mywidget").appendTo(document.body).css({
        width: width + 'px',
        position: 'absolute',
        top: ($(this).offset().top+top_offset).toString() + 'px',
        left: Math.round($(this).offset().left) + 'px';
    });
});
```

**Note**, outside of this, your id is not supposed to have spaces, according to HTML spec.  And, if you have a valid id, you would select it like this:

```
jQuery("#A0.R0.Main_Phone_Number")
```

Comment: If there anyway to do this? if (jQuery("#A0.R0.Main_Phone_Number")) then (do my other jQuery call)...

Comment: What do you mean "other call"?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It would help if you described what your html is doing and what you actually want to happen.