# Jquery selector - multiple classes/nested level?

Tags: jquery, selector

How do I select the following in JQuery?

```
<div class='A'>
  <span class='B C'>
     <p class='C D E'>
     </p>
  </span>
</div>
```

The following isn't working.

```
$('div.A > span.B.C > p.C.D.E')
```

Comment: Read the CSS [Selectors, Level 3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/), and the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/), and come back if you have any problems, after showing an actual attempt (not just "thinking about" one), and explaining the problem. Also: explain what you're trying to select.

Comment: Which element are you attempting to target? The `+` selector wouldn't appear to be appropriate in this case as it selects siblings, not children.

Comment: This was solved by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9754002/14427765).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do `$('.A').find('p.C')`

https://api.jquery.com/find/

> `.find()` : Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

Comment: It would be great if the people down-voting could **leave a reason why**.